# Serenity/JS: Why assertion in See.if return empty string sometimes?

Tags: protractor, cucumber, angular5, primeng, serenity-js

I am facing an issue with See.if() - it returns empty string sometimes.

Tech stack used:

1. Serenity/JS with cucumber and protractor
2. P-Growl - Primeng growl component
3. Chai as promised - expect method

Here is the error: **Assertion error: expected '' to include 'Operation success'**

**steps.ts**

```
this.Then(/^he should see the user (.*) success message$/, (severity) => {

    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); // Workaround fix for p-growl

    return stage.theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(
        Messages.called(severity)
    );
});
```

**Task.ts**

```
import { PerformsTasks, Task, Enter, Click, See, Is, Wait, Text } from 'serenity-js/protractor';

import { expect } from '../utils/expect';
import { ListUI } from '../components/ui';

export class Messages implements Task {

  constructor(private severity: string) { }

  static called(severity: string) {
    return new Messages(severity);
  }

  performAs(actor: PerformsTasks): PromiseLike<void> {
    if (this.severity.toLowerCase() === 'success') {
        return actor.attemptsTo(
            Wait.until(ListUI.message, Is.present()),
            See.if(
                Text.of(ListUI.message),
                actual => expect(actual).to.eventually.include('Operation Success')
            ),
            Click.on(ListUI.messageCloseWidget)
        );
    }
  }
}
```

**ui.ts**

```
import { Target, Text } from 'serenity-js/protractor';
import { by } from 'protractor';

export class ListUI {

  static message = Target.the('Message Widget')
    .located(by.id('messages'));

  static messageCloseWidget = Target.the('Message Close Widget')
    .located(by.css('#messages .ui-growl-icon-close'));
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Wait.for(Duration.ofSeconds(5)), before wait.until()

```
Wait.for(Duration.ofSeconds(5)),
Wait.until(ListUI.message, Is.present()),
```

Comment: If I go for wait.for, then what wait.until is doing internally ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by providing primeng growl message selector.

Provided exact selector for message (#messages .ui-growl-message).

Below code fixed:

```
import { Target, Text } from 'serenity-js/protractor';
import { by } from 'protractor';

export class ListUI {

  static message = Target.the('Message Widget')
    .located(by.css('#messages .ui-growl-message'));

  static messageCloseWidget = Target.the('Message Close Widget')
    .located(by.css('#messages .ui-growl-icon-close'));
}
```